# Chart.js throwing: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined, when plotting multiple charts in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, chart.js

**Charts.js** is not plotting the y-axis [jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/riddletom76/yeacfsw0/), i've tried to load both the chartOptions and chartData dynamically through json object which i'm planning to recieve through a request to web-api for the sake of demonstration i've included dummy json object which should plot the graph, the code runs and it performs two iterations of the loop and the chart is partially rendered(the y axes are not plotted), and throws "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**"

```
  var parsedJsonOption = JSON.parse(jsonContextOption);
  var parsedJsonData = JSON.parse(jsonContextData);
  var name;
  var graphType;


  function addNewChart(i){
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var newCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    newDiv.id = "graph-"+(i+1);
    newCanvas.id = "Chart-"+(i+1);
    newDiv.width = "600px";
    newDiv.height = "400px";
    newDiv.appendChild(newCanvas);
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(newDiv);
  }

  function randomColor(axisID){
    var retVal;
    switch(axisID){
    case 1: retVal = "rgba(255,0,0,1)";
        break;
    case 2: retVal = "rgba(0,255,0,1)";
        break;
    case 3: retVal = "rgba(0,0,255,1)";
        break; 
    case 4: retVal = "rgba(125,125,0,1)";
        break;
    case 5: retVal = "rgba(0,125,125,1)";
        break;
    case 6: retVal = "rgba(125,0,125,1)";
        break;
    }
    return retVal;
}

function getInitialChartOptions(){
    var chartOption = {
        scales: {
            xAxes:[{
                scaleLabel: {
                display: false,
                labelString: 'x-axis-0'
            },
                id: 'x-axis-0'
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'y-axis-0'
            },
                id: 'y-axis-0',
                display: true,
                position: 'left'
            }]
        },
        pan: {
            enabled: true,
            mode: 'x'
        },
        zoom: {
            enabled: true,
            mode: 'x'
        }
    };
    return chartOption;
}

function getInitialChartData(){
    var chartData = {
        datasets: [{
            borderColor: 'rgba(255,0,255,1)',
            yAxisID: 'y-axis-0',
            label: 'y-axis-0'//legend
        }]
    };
    return chartData;   
}

//method to load the options specified in the json
function addOptionToGraph(paramElement, i, chartOptions){   
    chartOptions.scales.yAxes[i].position = paramElement.yAxisPosition;
    chartOptions.scales.yAxes[i].scaleLabel.labelString = paramElement.yLabel;
    chartData.datasets[i].label = paramElement.name;
}

//plotting the chart
function plotTheChart(chartId, chartData, chartOptions, graphType){
    //plot 
    var myChart = document.getElementById(chartId).getContext('2d');
    var chartPlot = new Chart(myChart, {
        type: graphType,
        data: chartData,
        options: chartOptions
    });
    return chartPlot;
}

//method to load the chartOptions in the initialization phase of the chart
function showTicksAndAxis(chartPlot, option){
    for(var i=1;i<(option.parameterUIPropertiesCollection.length);i++){
        if(chartPlot.options.scales.yAxes[i-1].scaleLabel.labelString != option.parameterUIPropertiesCollection[i].yLabel){
            chartPlot.options.scales.yAxes[i].scaleLabel.display = true;
            chartPlot.options.scales.yAxes[i].display = true;               
        }
    }   
}


//Parameter data for the particular parameter as argument i.e. "x"
function GetParameterData(x){
    var parameterData = parsedJsonData.GraphParameterData[x];
    if (parameterData.ParameterValues != null) {
        return parameterData.ParameterValues;
    }
    return null;
}

function newDateString(days) {
    return moment().add(days, 'd');
}
var timeFormat = "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss";


//loading the data 
function setValue(j, arrayXValues, chartPlot){
    i=0;
    $.each(arrayXValues, function(key, datas) {
    key = newDateString(key);
    key = moment(key).format(timeFormat);
    chartPlot.data.labels[i] = key;
    chartPlot.data.datasets[j].data[i] = datas;
    i++;
  });
}


function loadData(chartPlot, option){
    for(var j = 0; j<chartPlot.data.datasets.length; j++){
        console.log("entered for "+j +" paramter");
        console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('body')) ;
        var arrayXValues = GetParameterData(j);
        if(arrayXValues != null){
            setValue(j, arrayXValues, chartPlot);
        }
    }
    showTicksAndAxis(chartPlot, option);//to show the hidden y-axes
    return chartPlot;
}
 for(var ChartIndex=0; ChartIndex<parsedJsonOption.length; ChartIndex++){
console.log(ChartIndex);
addNewChart(ChartIndex);

if(parsedJsonOption[ChartIndex] != null){
    var option = parsedJsonOption[ChartIndex];  
}else{
    continue;
}

name = option.graphName;



if (option.graphType == 0) {
    graphType = "line";
}

var chartOptions = getInitialChartOptions();
var chartData = getInitialChartData();

//Following is to add the chartData datasets according ton the number of parameters provided
var axisID = 1;
var numberOfParameters = parseInt(option.parameterUIPropertiesCollection.length); 
//to add the additional chartData in the chart based on the number of parameters

if(numberOfParameters > 1){
    while(numberOfParameters > 1){
        var yaxisid = "y-axis-" + axisID;
        var color = randomColor(axisID++);//increment the axisID for the next iteration
        var dataObj = {borderColor: color, yAxisID: yaxisid, label: yaxisid};
        chartData.datasets.push(dataObj);
        numberOfParameters--;   
    }   
}

//Following is to add the corresponding yaxes in the chartOptions 
axisID = 1;
var numberOfDatasets = chartData.datasets.length;

while(numberOfDatasets > 1){
    var yaxisid = "y-axis-"+axisID;
    var scaleLabelObj = {display: false, labelString: yaxisid};
    var optionObj = {scaleLabel: scaleLabelObj, id: yaxisid, display: false, postion: 'left'};
    chartOptions.scales.yAxes.push(optionObj);
    axisID++;
    numberOfDatasets--;
}

//adding the options before the data is loaded in the chart
for(var paramElementIndex=0;paramElementIndex<(option.parameterUIPropertiesCollection.length);paramElementIndex++){
    paramElement = option.parameterUIPropertiesCollection[paramElementIndex];
    addOptionToGraph(paramElement, paramElementIndex, chartOptions);
}
//console.log(i);
chartIdBasedOnIndex = ChartIndex;
var chartId = "Chart-"+(chartIdBasedOnIndex+1);


var chartPlot = plotTheChart(chartId, chartData, chartOptions, graphType);
chartPlot = loadData(chartPlot, option);
chartPlot.update();
}
```